# Coding in vb2012, error in FileStream

Tags: c#

i am building an application in C# in vb2012. i opened a new project and started editing the `MainPage.xaml.cs` file to write a main method and then a file read...

```
FileStream s = new FileStream("abc.txt", File.Read);
```

but it's showing error in `FileStream` and saying

> the type or namespace could not be found

Answer (score 1):

add

```
using System.IO;
```

to your using section.

Comment: its like net beans. no rebuilding, it shows errors then and there if corrected or not

Comment: I find that visual studio needs a rebuild to stop showing some errors and others it corrects immediately. If you've rebuilt and you're still having the problem, check out Sam I am's answer and see if that article applies to you.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you mean VS2012, not VB2012.  To use that class in C# add

```
using System.IO;
```

to the top of your class file.

The `FileStream` class is in the `System.IO` namespace, so adding the `using` directive lets the compiler search within that namespace for any classes you try to use. It will pull the `File` enumeration from there as well.

**ALSO**

`File.Read` is a method, not an enumeration.  Use

```
FileStream s = new FileStream("abc.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

instead